# Resources for learning Python after having experience in C/C++

Tags: python

In my present job a lot of ad-hoc text processing is required. I have been coding in C for 5+ years and have some exposure to STL of C++. I decided to try out Python, and so far the combination of google and stackoverflow is working well. But it would be great if I can follow some material (lecture/book) to formally learn the language, which will ensure that I haven't missed any important aspect of the same.

Having done some coding before, I don't want a beginner level book/lecture. Any suggestions?

I have used the "Head First Java" book, what do you people think of the "Head First Python" book?

Comment: Text Processing in Python may have been written just for you.  See http://gnosis.cx/TPiP/.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Learning Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/852554/learning-python)

Answer (score 3):

The **Google Python Class** should give you a hands on guide (don't forget to check the video tutorials and the coding exercises):

http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/

Oh, and you might want to read the books the others have posted.

For the **text processing** you should check the **Regular Expressions** video (which is available on the sidebar) and tutorial page: http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/regular-expressions.html

Answer (score 1):

[The Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) is actually an excellent reference. It isn't targeted at teaching you how to program, it's written to show you *how to python*, including the specifics of the language and neat tricks it includes (like [else clauses on loops](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)).

Comment: Thanks to you, I just learnt something cool ... else clauses on loops ... being from C/C++ background, this is something I would have never explored.

Answer (score 1):

[Dive into Python](http://diveintopython3.ep.io/) is a great book for experienced programmers coming to Python and wanting to quickly grok its syntax and special features (the latest version is for Python 3, but it's quite backwards compatible). Beyond that, keep the [Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/index.html) close at hand; one of the biggest advantages of Python is its included batteries.

That said, for text processing... are you in a UNIX environment? Bash is king for that sort of work.

Comment: Yes I'm in Unix. I use the tools sort, join, grep, sed for a lot of this stuff, but its inadequate beyond a point. I tried using awk and perl, but wanted something which is more general purpose (than awk) and has easier to read syntax (than perl).

Comment: I don't think bash is the most appealing option for text processing... python (or perl) on the other hand... in python you have the raw strings (that let you write a regular expression with no escaping chars like in other languages).

Answer (score -1):

I don't use python myself, but I have been meaning to learn and I have been repeatedly recommended [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/).  It's free in HTML but there are epub and physical copies you can order as well.

Comment: Caveat: Learn Python the Hard Way is explicitly for newcomers to computer science. The OP clearly isn't.